# Proguard issues with Gradle 3.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-proguard

I'm trying to create an APK using ProGuard and the new Gradle 3.0.0 version. I'm getting a lot of warnings on classes that I thought I ignored in my ProGuard configuration file. The same configuration works well with Gradle 2.3.3 but seems to break on 3.0.0. The warnings are so many it's almost not reading the ProGuard configuration at all.

My build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'


    }

}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }

    }
}
android{
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }

        }




compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 27
testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
multiDexEnabled true

}
```

Proguard warning below.

```
    Warning: library class android.animation.FloatArrayEvaluator extends or implements program class android.animation.TypeEvaluator
    Warning: library class android.animation.IntArrayEvaluator extends or implements program class android.animation.TypeEvaluator
    Warning: library class android.animation.PointFEvaluator extends or implements program class android.animation.TypeEvaluator
    Warning: library class android.animation.RectEvaluator extends or implements program class android.animation.TypeEvaluator
    Warning: library class android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.AlarmManager$AlarmClockInfo extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.AuthenticationRequiredException extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.AutomaticZenRule extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.Notification$Action extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.Notification$DecoratedCustomViewStyle extends or implements program class android.app.Notification$Style
    Warning: library class android.app.Notification$MediaStyle extends or implements program class android.app.Notification$Style
    Warning: library class android.app.Notification$MessagingStyle extends or implements program class android.app.Notification$Style
    Warning: library class android.app.NotificationChannel extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.NotificationChannelGroup extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.NotificationManager$Policy extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.PictureInPictureParams extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.Presentation extends or implements program class android.app.Dialog
    Warning: library class android.app.RemoteAction extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.RemoteInput extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.VoiceInteractor$PickOptionRequest$Option extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.VoiceInteractor$Prompt extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.WallpaperColors extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.admin.ConnectEvent extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.admin.DeviceAdminService extends or implements program class android.app.Service
    Warning: library class android.app.admin.DnsEvent extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.admin.NetworkEvent extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.admin.SecurityLog$SecurityEvent extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.admin.SystemUpdateInfo extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.admin.SystemUpdatePolicy extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.assist.AssistContent extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.assist.AssistStructure extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.job.JobInfo extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable

    Warning: library class android.util.FloatProperty extends or implements program class android.util.Property
    Warning: library class android.util.IntProperty extends or implements program class android.util.Property
    Warning: library class android.view.ActionMode$Callback2 extends or implements program class android.view.ActionMode$Callback
    Warning: library class android.view.Display$HdrCapabilities extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.view.Display$Mode extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.view.DragAndDropPermissions extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.view.KeyboardShortcutGroup extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.view.KeyboardShortcutInfo extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.view.PointerIcon extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.view.WindowAnimationFrameStats extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.view.WindowContentFrameStats extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.view.WindowId extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityWindowInfo extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.view.animation.BaseInterpolator extends or implements program class android.view.animation.Interpolator
    Warning: library class android.view.autofill.AutofillId extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.view.autofill.AutofillValue extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.view.inputmethod.CursorAnchorInfo extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.view.inputmethod.InputContentInfo extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.widget.ActionMenuView extends or implements program class android.widget.LinearLayout
    Warning: library class android.widget.ActionMenuView$LayoutParams extends or implements program class android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

    Warning: library class android.app.RemoteInput depends on program class android.content.Intent
    Warning: library class android.app.RemoteInput depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.app.RemoteInput depends on program class android.content.Intent
    Warning: library class android.app.RemoteInput depends on program class android.os.Parcel
    Warning: library class android.app.RemoteInput$Builder depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.app.RemoteInput$Builder depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.app.SharedElementCallback depends on program class android.view.View
    Warning: library class android.app.SharedElementCallback depends on program class android.graphics.Matrix
    Warning: library class android.app.SharedElementCallback depends on program class android.graphics.RectF
    Warning: library class android.app.SharedElementCallback depends on program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.app.SharedElementCallback depends on program class android.content.Context

    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaController$TransportControls depends on program class android.net.Uri
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaController$TransportControls depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaController$TransportControls depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaController$TransportControls depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession depends on program class android.content.Context
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession depends on program class android.os.Handler
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession depends on program class android.app.PendingIntent
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession depends on program class android.app.PendingIntent
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession$Callback depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession$Callback depends on program class android.os.ResultReceiver
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession$Callback depends on program class android.content.Intent
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession$Callback depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession$Callback depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession$Callback depends on program class android.net.Uri
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession$Callback depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession$Callback depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession$Callback depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession$Callback depends on program class android.net.Uri
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession$Callback depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession$Callback depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession$QueueItem depends on program class android.os.Parcelable$Creator
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession$QueueItem depends on program class android.os.Parcel
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession$Token depends on program class android.os.Parcelable$Creator
    Warning: library class android.media.session.MediaSession$Token depends on program class android.os.Parcel
    Warning: library class android.media.session.PlaybackState depends on program class android.os.Parcelable$Creator
    Warning: library class android.media.session.PlaybackState depends on program class android.os.Parcel
    Warning: library class android.media.session.PlaybackState depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.media.session.PlaybackState$Builder depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.media.session.PlaybackState$CustomAction depends on program class android.os.Parcelable$Creator
    Warning: library class android.media.session.PlaybackState$CustomAction depends on program class android.os.Parcel
    Warning: library class android.media.session.PlaybackState$CustomAction depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.media.session.PlaybackState$CustomAction$Builder depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.net.Network depends on program class android.os.Parcelable$Creator
    Warning: library class android.net.Network depends on program class android.os.Parcel
    Warning: library class android.os.LocaleList depends on program class android.os.Parcelable$Creator
    Warning: library class android.os.LocaleList depends on program class android.os.Parcel
    Warning: library class android.os.PersistableBundle depends on program class android.os.Parcelable$Creator
    Warning: library class android.os.PersistableBundle depends on program class android.os.Parcel
    Warning: library class android.os.UserManager depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.os.UserManager depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.net.Uri

    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.net.Uri
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.net.Uri
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.content.Context
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.net.Uri
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.net.Uri
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.net.Uri
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.net.Uri
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.net.Uri
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.net.Uri
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.content.ContentResolver
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.net.Uri
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.graphics.Point
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.os.CancellationSignal
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.graphics.Bitmap
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.content.ContentResolver
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.net.Uri
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.net.Uri
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.content.ContentResolver
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.net.Uri
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.net.Uri
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.content.ContentResolver
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.net.Uri
    Warning: library class android.provider.DocumentsContract depends on program class android.content.ContentResolver

    Warning: library class android.security.KeyPairGeneratorSpec depends on program class android.content.Context
    Warning: library class android.security.KeyPairGeneratorSpec$Builder depends on program class android.content.Context
    Warning: library class android.service.media.MediaBrowserService depends on program class android.content.Intent
    Warning: library class android.service.media.MediaBrowserService depends on program class android.os.IBinder
    Warning: library class android.service.media.MediaBrowserService depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.service.media.MediaBrowserService depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.service.media.MediaBrowserService depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.service.media.MediaBrowserService depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.service.media.MediaBrowserService$BrowserRoot depends on program class android.os.Bundle
    Warning: library class android.service.media.MediaBrowserService$BrowserRoot depends on program class android.os.Bundle

    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.util.AttributeSet
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.content.Context
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.content.Context
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.view.View$OnClickListener
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.view.Menu
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.os.Parcelable
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.view.MotionEvent
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.util.AttributeSet
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.util.AttributeSet
    Warning: library class android.widget.Toolbar depends on program class android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams

    Note: there were 15 references to unknown classes.
          You should check your configuration for typos.
          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
    Note: there were 21 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
          You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)

    Warning: there were 928 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
             You must avoid such dependencies since the program classes will be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
             (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)
    Warning: there were 53 unresolved references to program class members.
             Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
             You may need to recompile the code.
             (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)

    Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    :transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForCouchdbRelease FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForCouchdbRelease'.
    > Job failed, see logs for details
```

Comment: You have to write proguard rules by yourself in `proguard-rules.pro`.

Comment: I have the same issue. For some reason the apk contains all the classes from the android.jar with stubbed methods. If I add `-dontwarn android.**` to my `proguard-rules.pro` file the apk is built. When I run it I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub! at android.content.g.<init>(Unknown Source) ...`.

Comment: I have the same exact issue. APK is built successfully on 2.3.3. Any update?

Comment: I have the same issue, do you have any updates?

Comment: Experiencing the same when running a release build, has anyone found solution to this? It seems like proguard is not being executed at all. Or might be a change of structure?

Comment: Same error here. Any update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've upgraded to gradle 3.0.1 and most of the warnings are gone. If you're still on 3.0.0 then use this in your proguard file

```
-dontwarn android.**
```

Not ideal but gets it working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, although my case is kind of unique, here is my solution:

After upgrading to the new 3.0.1 version (`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1`), I saw fewer warnings (originally I had >3000 warnings).
The source of my problem was that I used a library which had a dependency on the whole android framework (This one: https://github.com/tony19/logback-android, the issue [#73](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/issues/73)).

I also looked into the dependencies (`./gradlew app:dependenices`), because I had libraries which depends on the old apache http client, which also causes some warnings. I had to eliminate them as well.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you

`Enabling ProGuard for local library modules no longer affects the library's code. Instead, you should run ProGuard on the app module that consumes the library.`

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

Comment: Could you develop your answer a bit more with an example at least? Answers that are barely an url aren't useful.